# Whats the best way to display information in Android

Tags: android, listview

I am currently making an android application which need to present a lot of information from different arrays. On each horizontal line there's gonna be four different texts and then I need to be able to scroll through all information displayed. I know ListView is one way to go, problem is I dont know how to use four text views horizontally in a ListView. Any tips or help to get the best way to present the information would be grealy appreciated.

Basically like this:

[image]

Comment: Try this: [Android Multi column ListView](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-multi-column-listview/)

Comment: Is it possible to do without HashMap?

Comment: you can also create a user defined class and then prepare an arraylist of objects of this class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to extend ArrayAdapter and override getView() of Array Adapter.

Comment: yeah, inflate a horizontal linear layout with 4 textviews in it. simplest and effective

Comment: Can you give example? Not really sure what you mean.

Comment: Check out this link - http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/11/android-full-app-part-6-customized-list.html